# gedit `Comment Code` plugin installed but not working

Tags: 14.04, gedit, plugins

I seem to have no trouble installing GEdit plugins, and in general GEdit seems to be working OK.  It also seems like the plugins got installed (at least to some degree) because the *Comment code* and *Uncomment code* options appear under the Edit tab.

The only problem is that these commenting functions are greyed out and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> similarly has no effect.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Which plugin do you mean?

Comment: It's the "Code Comment" plugin, but I installed it just as part of a batch of standard plugins with `sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins` as recommended at https://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2015/05/22/code-comment-gedit-plugin/

Comment: Can you please provide a file for which it does not work? It must be a language recognised by the plugin itself, obviously.

Comment: @dadexix86, what is obvious to you was not to me.  I'll give you credit if you post as a solution.  I was trying it on a flat text file with no extension, assuming that it should default to #, but it works fine as soon as I add a specific language extension.

Comment: Done! :) Indeed, it defaults to None. If you think about it, there is no point in preferring one comment style over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file should be of a recognised language by gedit, so that the plugin knows which comments it should use (`#`, `--`, `<--`...`>`, `/*`...`*/`, ecc...)

Comment: to make it perfectly clear for novices as myself, telling gedit what language to use is as simple as including the standard language extension on the file you are editing.   So `myfile.py` if you're doing python, or `myfile.R` if you're doing R, etc.